# How to prove that a rational function is a polynomial

Tags: functions, polynomials, rational-functions

$\newcommand\Q{\mathbb Q}$I have a rational function $f(\vec x)$ over $\Q$ in many variables (7 variables). I do not know what $f$ is, but I can evaluate it for random choices of $x_1,\dots,x_7\in \Q$ without $x_i$ for any $i=1,\dots, 7$. I always get a polynomial over $x_i$. This indicates to me that $f$ may indeed be a polynomial. If I can evaluate $f$ in this way, is there a smart way to prove that $f$ is a polynomial?

**Edit**: We may assume that we know what the upper bound of the total degrees of the numerator and the denominator are.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're saying. If you know the values of $f(x)$ for every $x,$ then surely you know $f$ completely?

Comment: Theortically yes, but I can only manually evaluate $f$ for finitely many choices of $x$ and not for all $x$.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the OP can evaluate $f(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_6,x_7)$ as a function of the variable $x_7$ for any rational numbers $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_6$, and the answer always turns out to be a polynomial (and similarly where any of the $x_j$ is singled out, not just $x_7$).

Comment: I don't know a solution right away but this is an interesting problem for sure!

Comment: @Greg Martin. Indeed, and "always" means here for the many times I have tried. I can try any values for which can help me eventually prove it is a polynomial, but I am not yet sure how.

Comment: For any finite number of such evaluations, there exists a non-polynomial rational function that will look like a polynomial after the evaluations—think of functions like $1/(1+\prod_{j=1}^7(x_j-\alpha_j))$. So any progress will depend upon how the "random" choices are chosen.

Comment: Do you KNOW that for any choice of $x_1,\dots,x_7$, where one of these stays a variable you get a polynomial, or have you only tried for finitely many? Because I think, for any finite number of evaluations you can "build" a rational function that will be polynomial after the evaluation.  It's  a different story if you knew it holds for all possible evaluations. PS:  I just saw that @GregMartin wrote something similar.

Comment: @Guenterino I don't know this. But I think I can figure what the upper bound of (total) degrees of the numerator and the denominator is.

Comment: This would actually help, because if you know a limit for the degree of the denominator there is a limit for the number of evaluations for which a construction such as @GregMartin 's is possible.

Comment: Yeah, a known upper bound on degrees changes the answer from "no" to "probably". Now to see if we can come up with a proof, and then maybe a minimum number of evaluations needed.

Comment: To clarify once again: Do you know something like $f(1,2,3,4,5,6,x)=x^2$ or do you only know that this maps $0\mapsto 0$, $\pm1\mapsto 1$, $\pm2\mapsto 4$, $\pm3\mapsto 9$?

Comment: I know something like the first one (so exactly the univariate polynomial).